# Qt taking a widget out of a layout, but maintaining current position

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QVBoxLayout where I have stacked QHBoxLayout objects, each of which has 1-2 widgets in it. One of them contains a long label and a button next to it. However, when the label resizes in height and stretches the layout vertically, the button moves downwards in order to be aligned with the vertical middle of the label. How can I prevent the button from moving when the layout stretches? Can I take it out of the layout, but leave it at the same coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

You should put the button into another vertical layout, and add a spacer:

```
-----------------------------------
|                        | BUTTON |
|                        |---------
|   whatever you need    |vertical|
|      to have here      |   |    |
|                        | spacer |
-----------------------------------
```

[image]

Comment: This could have been a simple grid, you then save on one vertical layout.

Answer (score 2):

You can set alignment for your button to prevent it moving:

`layout->setAlignment(btn, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignTop)`

Taking button from layout is bad idea. You will probably encounter memory leak. Also manual widget positioning can be pretty complex.

Comment: "Taking button from layout is bad idea. You will probably encounter memory leak." It's not a bad idea per se, and no memory leaks need to happen. You'd need to qualify this advice with some examples to make it useful, as it stands it's useless FUD. It simply is not necessary in this case: the question was "can I make it behave properly, *or else* can I make it work by taking the button out of the layout". You could pretty much remove the last paragraph from the answer, since it doesn't apply: you've provided a better solution!

Comment: If by removing we mean setting button parent widget to 0 - then Qt does not remove this button when this widget will be removed. This is a memory leak.